# I want to develop a application for CRM in C#

Tags: .net, asp.net, database, data-structures, crm

I need some project that I can read it's source code and learn the design structure from it.This project should have a database layer, and business rule layer, anyone has suggestions?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: I want to develop a desktop application, so don't introduce me the asp.net

Comment: but your you are tagging question asp.net and you have not clearly state in  your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about [dotnetnuke](http://dotnetnuke.com)
you can get the source from their website

Comment: Isn't dotnetnuke an asp.net application?

Answer (score 0):

You can look around on CodePlex for good open source C# code.

[Asp.NET CRM](http://crm.codeplex.com/) is one option

Comment: I want to develop a desktop application, so don't introduce me the asp.net. anyway thanks in advance !

Answer (score -1):

A few open source CRM's come to mind:

- [SugarCRM](http://www.sugarcrm.com/crm/)
- [OpenCRX](http://www.opencrx.org/)
- [VTiger](http://www.vtiger.com/)